# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, space, head

what my program do : i write value on sqlserver ( i write 2 400 000 times)

my problem : doesn't have enough head space but i'm working on 32bit computer and i can't force JVM to allocated enough space(.

do you have a solution or can you orient me to methods to solve this problem.

i have already try System.gc().

my code:

```
int nul = 0;
    int total = 0;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        System.out.println("Driver O.K.");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://BCNSDBA042\\DEV_CP1_CI_AS";
        String user = "REMINDINTDATA";
        String passwd = "REMINDINTDATA";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
        System.out.println("Connexion effective !");
        Statement state = conn.createStatement();
        File indexDirectory = new File("D:\\index\\IdxDOSSIER\\data\\index");
        DirectoryReader r = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory
                .open(indexDirectory));
        int num = r.numDocs();
        System.out.println("clean en attente");
        state.executeUpdate("delete from Document_solr ");
        System.out.println("clean effectué");
        int i = 0;
        String commande = null;
        while (i < num) {
            commande = "INSERT INTO Document_solr (DC_KEY) VALUES";
            Document d = r.document(i);
            for (int k = 0; k < 100 && (i + k) < num; k++) {
                d = r.document(i + k);
                if ((i + k) == num - 1) {
                    if (d.get("DC_KEY") != null) {
                        commande = commande + "(" + d.get("DC_KEY") + ")";
                    } else {
                        commande = commande.substring(0,
                                commande.length() - 1);
                        nul++;
                    }
                    total++;
                } else {
                    total++;
                    d = r.document(i + k);
                    if (d.get("DC_KEY") != null) {
                        if (k != 99) {
                            commande = commande + "(" + d.get("DC_KEY")
                                    + ")" + ",";
                        } else {
                            commande = commande + "(" + d.get("DC_KEY")
                                    + ")";
                        }

                    } else {

                        nul++;
                        k--;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Fichier traiter : " + i);
            System.out.println(commande);
            state.executeUpdate(commande);
            i = i + 100;
        }
        r.close();
        state.close();
        // result.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

can i execute my program in in twice or tree time ?(without having to run it again)

edit:
i run mat with dump head it's said that the leak memory come from :

The thread java.lang.Thread @ 0x24d60790 main keeps local variables with total size 666 611 008 (99,88%) bytes.

The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.Thread" loaded by "system class loader>".

Comment: Why don't you use batch update with prepared statement for updating such huge amount of records. However, to overcome from OutOfMemory you will have to either change your approach or provide memory to JVM

Comment: can you tell me more about or where i can find some explanation because i'm a really good programmer (i'm still in school)

Comment: i think i have a huge memory leak ! if you have the same error than me it can be that.

Comment: i think that my only solution is paging !